# How do I detect duplicates in two worksheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

I have 1 Google Sheet with 2 worksheets:

- Worksheet "1" has 1 column A with 5 lines of data (AAA, AAB, AAC, AAD, AAE)
- Worksheet "2" has 1 column A with 5 lines of data (AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD, EEE)

I would like to automatically detect that AAA is, in fact, a duplicate since it exists in both worksheets. I would like to detect this in worksheet "2".

I understand this should be done by using Conditional Formatting but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

It took a while but I have found it myself. I used Confitional Formatting in the 2nd worksheet in column A:

```
=(countif($A$2:$A,A2)+countif(indirect("sheet1!$A$2:$A"),A2))>1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=FILTER(A2, COUNTIF(INDIRECT("sheet1!A2:A"), A2))
```

[image: 0]